# Question about running bibtex in Texniccenter?

Tags: bibtex

I'm trying to use bibtex in Texniccenter, using the Bibtex in 60 seconds found here: http://www.hep.man.ac.uk/u/jenny/jcwdocs/latex/bibtexbasics.html

Step 5 says: When processing the file, you need to do: latex filename, bibtex filename, latex filename, latex filename.

I'm using Texniccenter, but I don't know what this step means or how to perform it. Under the Build>Define output profiles... tab I have "Do not use Bibtex in this profile" box unchecked. Do I need to change other things?

Comment: That should be sufficient. However, you might need to click on the "Compile" button 2-3 times as each click will only result in latex being called once.

Comment: You also have the alternative to build just the `BibTeX` part in `Build--->BibTeX`.  Naturally, as Trefex said, you need to check the `Uses BibTeX` option in your `project properties`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an installed version of Perl or can install it (e.g. from http://www.activestate.com/perl/) then you can use the program latexmk.exe, which comes with any TeX distribution. Create a new output format by copying the "LaTeX->PDF" one:

- rename it to "LaTeXmk"
- replace "pdflatex.exe" with "latexmk.exe"
- insert -pdf "%wm"  as optional arguments.

The Perl script `latexmk` controlls the number of runnings and the use of `bibtex/biber` and/or `makeindex`.

The screenshot shows the window with german text but it is selfexplanatory

[image]